# how to run JSCover on windows

Tags: code-coverage, jasmine

I've spent quite some time to try using the JSCover that allows you to monitor code coverage of your javascript code. As compelling as it may sound, it does not seem to be a straight forward deal.

here is the manual that they have and I can sworn that I tried following the instructions given here but I still cannot get to run their basic example.

http://tntim96.github.io/JSCover/manual/manual.xml#gettingStarted

I am unable to run the "example-server.sh"...I am pretty sure that I might be missing something...but I am unable to figure it out...My question is if anyone here have tried running this JSCover on windows? if yes, can you help me in doing the same...

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows, try running example-server.bat.

Alternatively, you can try running it from the command line using:

```
java -jar target/dist/JSCover-all.jar -ws --branch --document-root=doc/example --report-dir=target
```

Make sure you have Java installed, and are running from in the JSCover directory root. If you still get an error, can you post the details?

Also, for a quick response, try posting the question at: https://github.com/tntim96/JSCover/issues